# Rails runs a different application to current path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two Rails projects (project1: `3.2.11`, `project2`: 4.2.4), whose folders are located in the parent folder called `Projects`. In the terminal, when current path is `/Users/me/Projects/project1` then, run `rails s`, when I visit `localhost:3000`, the project launched is the other one: `/Users/me/Projects/project2`, not the project I start from. Does anyone know why this behaviour is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I had to run my `project1` over other port, meanwhile `project2` over port 3000.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the absolute path.

```
cd /Users/me/Projects/project1 && script/rails server
```